# How to get closer with my budgies?

Tags: training, birds, budgerigar

I have 2 budgies (male and female) since last November but there are 2 problems:

First, they appear really scared of me; they're not chicks so I know it takes time to become friends with them but they seem to still be really scared of me.

Second, they're really loud. I know they are budgies, so they make noise and I don't mind that, but they're often too loud, especially the male budgie. I did some research and it seems that there was one way to work on the noise: when they start to make noise, I should ignore and once they stop, give them some treats.

I want to try solving the noise problem way, but they seem to be really scared of me so I can't close enough to give them treats. Are there any suggestions on how I can gain their trust?

Comment: How are you keeping them? What size cage, and could they fly around the room if they came out of it? (Asking because if you became "guy that has the tasty food when we have fun flying around!" would make things easier treatwise)

Comment: The cage is pretty big (30-Inch Long, 18-Inch Wide, 18-Inch High with 3/8-Inch wire spacing) and I think they could fly if they came out of the cage ( I assumed). and I don't understand your parenthesis... can you explain more? sorry